# Remove duplicate commits introduced after bad rebase(s)

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I have 2 branches, `master` & `feature`. Master occasionally receives small tweaks that are needed to go live quickly. Once these tweaks are done, `master` is rebased into `feature` so that feature is kept up to date.

The files changed on master are generally not related to the bulk of the development on `feature` but I've been getting a high number of complicated 3 way merge conflicts.

After looking at the commit log of `feature`, I've found the problem to be several duplicates and I'm attempting to solve it with an interactive rebase.

My question is:

Is this the best solution for the problem, and if so can I just drop the duplicates and essentially build the history how I expect it to look? Also which duplicates would I drop, higher(older original) or lower (newer duplicates).

**Abstract listing taken from `git rebase master -i`:**

```
pick 0eb277c Commit A
pick ced2556 Commit B
pick 640e049 Commit C
pick b248ff7 Commit D
pick 9903094 Commit E
pick ebc279d Commit A
pick 313385b Commit F
pick 0d55178 Commit G
pick c8f09f9 Commit H
pick e877be3 Commit I
pick 9859aa0 Commit J
pick c3c8e0f Commit K
pick 8abc68c Commit L
pick 84a5c89 Commit A
pick 30570e4 Commit B
pick 937ff2f Commit C
pick 8e6d911 Commit D
pick 1dd3a09 Commit E
pick fe79288 Commit F
pick 9e790bb Commit G
pick 0924916 Commit H
pick 90d59d7 Commit I
pick ba06c55 Commit J
pick 7452fad Commit K  ** Dupes end here** and features then has 30+ more commits.
pick d1dca3d Commit M
pick 6c85f76 Commit N
pick ad53b78 Commit O
pick f166471 Commit P
```

Comment: You can use `git rebase -i HEAD~x` replace `x` with whichever number of commits you want to look at top to bottom e.g `git rebase -i HEAD~3` this will give you three last commits. You can then select which commits you want to preserve and which ones you want to delete.

Comment: Commits 0eb277c and ebc279d are marked as being both commit A, but obviously their sha1 are different, thus those are different commits. Actually I don't see any duplicated commits in the sha1 list.

Comment: I mean the duplicate loosely, the commit messages are the same and the code thats applied is the same. But it is duplicated and saved as a new commit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To remove the duplicate commits you must go through the list generated by `git rebase master -i` and drop the duplicates by navigating up and down the list using the arrow keys pressing <kbd>d</kbd> on the commits you want to `drop`.

*(`master` can be replaced with a commmit hash or any valid re-base point)*

Once you have deleted all the duplicates and have a commit list that looks how you expect the history to look, exit the rebase screen by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> and typing `!wq` and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The re-base will then continue and apply the list of commits you `pick`ed onto your re-base point.

Comment: Great answer, just keep in mind that it references `vim` as git commit text editor. Eg I have `nano` set as the editor, and the hotkeys are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler approach than what the accepted answer suggests. Switch to `feature` and run the regular `git rebase master`. Unlike interactive rebase, the non-interactive one is smart enough not to apply the same changes twice, resulting in a clear, linear commit history.