# Remove duplicate commits after rebase and cherrypick in a public repository

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have a github repository of an open-source project – [Cubes](https://github.com/dataBrewery/cubes/). For various reasons, rebase and cherry-picking was applied to the repository in not very cautious manner. History was also edited due to committed information that was not meant to be public. Some actions spanning multiple commits seem to be applied to two clones independently and afterwards the two clones were merged into one, resulting in even more duplicates.

In short and honestly: there was a huge lack of proper git hygiene and the history is now very messy and redundant. See pictures below.

I would like to remove whole duplicate branches from the repository.

Questions:

- What is the best approach to solve this problem of cleaning-up huge amount of duplicate commits (actually, duplicate branches)?
- What are the alternatives to the [interactive rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454532/remove-duplicate-commits-introduced-after-bad-rebases) `git rebase -i`?
- If the interactive rebase is the way to go, how damaging it would be to do it to a public facing repository? I know there are recommendations of not doing it.

Some visualisations of the situation:

[image: Example of duplicate commits]

[image: Example of triple-commits]

Comment: Just start over. I see nothing in your commit messages that provide any useful value to the history anyway. Except maybe release versions

Comment: First, I am not a big fan of using rebase on anything but release milestones (and possibly pre-release on the complexity of the release process).  I don't think the extra time of sorting through incremental commits is as big a problem as trying to track something down or clean something up.  

There are a lot of considerations you aren't mentioning, including your release process.  Why are "duplicate branches" a problem, not always a bad thing depending on the process.  Why would "public facing" repository solve anything?.  Why is deleting a branch a problem for you?

Comment: You could potentially do another rebase on top of an old commit. I don't even want to try to explain how to accomplish this successfully though. You basically would rebase interactive and remove the dupes you don't want. This can get really bad though so I don't suggest it

Comment: Too many competing branches. Let's make one new universal branch! https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @SteveHarris This dates 3-5 years back where there was no formal release process in the library itself and in the organization where custom development happened they had common practice of using `rebase` + `push --hard`. The "duplicate branches" are not a serious/blocking problem, just wanted to get rid of them for having more transparent history (they were created by mistake and bad practices).

Comment: I would not do anything about the history itself, but rather check for options in your git UI to not show the merged branches (a.k.a "follow first parent") and other visualization options

Answer (score 0):

One way make history look nicer without rewriting it is replacing commits with "`git replace`". So you run:

```
git replace --edit {commit}
```

for the commit where you "duplicated" branch is merged to and in the editor window remove all "parent" lines except the first one. Then you won't see the branch in git clients, though it would be still there. You can push and fetch the replacement with commands, to make them visible by the whole team:

```
git push origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
git fetch origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
```