# Fix Duplicate Commits from Git Rebase

Tags: git, merge, workflow, rebase

I'm having a bit of trouble learning GIT and developing my own workflow. I have an environment where we are tracking stock code updates and then applying our custom changes on top of each new version of stock code. As of now, I have our custom changes on top of our newly updated code, but I have multiple duplicates on the branch I just moved over as well as the old branch built on top of the old code.

```
Old Stock - New Stock - a - b - c - d - e
          \ a - b - c - d - **e** -----/(merged)
```

At this point I am just scared of doing more rebases and merging so this may be a silly question, but I am just wondering how to get rid of that bottom branch with duplicate commits but keep the one e commit on my top Stock branch.

Comment: what about just cherry-picking it over? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: @dogs_breath-I did not know about cherry pick. I suppose that could have been an option before I merged over the new change... Regardless I am still wondering how to get rid of all the duplicate commits on the second branch, or simply get rid of the second branch altogether.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what you need without knowing the details of any merge conflicts, etc. in your branches. In general, the easiest thing to do is an interactive rebase. something like '''git rebase -i <new stock>''' and that will let you pick out commits you don't want to include.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454532/remove-duplicate-commits-introduced-after-bad-rebases/38457832

Comment: That was a great idea to rebase, and now I realize I should have given you more information. If I were to rebase, I also have branches after my 'e' commit which would be still tied to the files I am trying to get rid of. Long story short, would I have to do an interactive rebase on my original branch, and both branches?